# How to reduce an image collection by numbers matching conditions in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there way to reduce an image collection by numbers how many images matching conditions?

For example, I want to create a new image to visualize how many days meet some conditions in a period.

[image: ref image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to convert an image collection to an image by combining all the pixels in some way for each spatial location, the solution is `ImageCollection.reduce`. In this case, we can use the `ee.Reducer.count` reducer to count the number of pixels meeting the condition.

JavaScript example:

```js
var daysMeetingConditionImage = imageCollectionOfDayImages
  .map(function (image) {
    // Apply the condition, whatever it is, as a mask.
    // Masked-off pixels will not be counted.
    return image.updateMask(
       image.select('B2').gt(7)  // Change this to whatever your per-pixel condition is
    );
  })
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.count());
```

Comment: Thanks! I learnt using the combination of updateMask and Reducer.count was the solution.